# converting csv file to another csv choosing specific columns python

Tags: python, list, csv

i am trying to convert a csv file with the following columns:

```
ID,Name,Postcode,State,Suburb,Lat,Lon
1,Hurstville Store,1493,NSW,Hurstville,-33.975869,151.088939
```

I want to make a new csv with only the Name, Lat, Lon columns but im getting this error: 
header = csvReader.next()
AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'

here is my code so far:

```
import csv

# Set up input and output variables for the script
storeLoc = open("store_locations.csv", "r")

# Set up CSV reader and process the header
csvReader = csv.reader(storeLoc)
header = csvReader.next()
nameIndex = header.index("Name")
latIndex = header.index("Lat")
lonIndex = header.index("Lon")

# Make an empty list
coordList = []

# Loop through the lines in the file and get each coordinate
for row in csvReader:
name = row[nameIndex]
lat = row[latIndex]
lon = row[lonIndex]
coordList.append([name,lat,lon])

# Print the coordinate list
print(coordList)
coordList.append([name,lat,lon])

stores = open('store_coords.csv','w', newline='')
```

thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 1):

That code will work in Python 2, i.e `csv.reader` objects have a `next()` method. However, in Python 3 there is no such method.

Instead, and this works in both versions of Python, use `next(reader)`:

```
import csv

# Set up input and output variables for the script
storeLoc = open("store_locations.csv", "r")

# Set up CSV reader and process the header
csvReader = csv.reader(storeLoc)
header = next(csvReader)
```

---

Here is a concise way of writing it using the csv module:

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

name_lat_lon = itemgetter(1, 5, 6)

with open('store_locations.csv') as infile, open('store_coords.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    csv.writer(outfile).writerows(name_lat_lon(row) for row in csv.reader(infile))
```

More concise still:

```
import csv

with open('store_locations.csv') as infile, open('store_coords.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    csv.writer(outfile).writerows((row[1], row[5], row[6]) for row in csv.reader(infile))
```

Or even more so if certain assumptions are made about the CSV delimiter:

```
with open('store_locations.csv') as infile, open('store_coords.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(','.join((row[1], row[5], row[6])) for row in (line.split(',') for line in infile))
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response i found a super easy solution in another thread

Comment: @Blake: No problem. I doubt that your "super easy solution" is better or easier than this one.

Comment: i found a solution using petl;

Comment: from petl import fromcsv, look, cut, tocsv

#Load the table
originalFile = fromcsv('store_locations.csv')
# Alter the colums
newFile = cut(originalFile, 'Name','Lat','Lon')
# Save to new file
tocsv(newFile, 'store_coords.csv')

Comment: That's not a solution to the specific problem that you had using `next()` it just obviates the problem (not that there's anything wrong with that if you have learned something).

Comment: i didnt mean to come across as knocking your solution. im terrible with these comments i keep trying to enter new line but instead post the comment abruptly. iv gone with the petl options for converting a new csv as it definitely shortens my code. i do appreciate your help tho!

Comment: @Blake: that's OK, I didn't take it badly, I just thought that you should understand the reason for the problem that you had, and point out that this answer answers the question that you actually had. As a demonstration I have added a concise way to filter columns using just the standard `csv` module. It's pretty short.

Comment: Hi @mhawke, Using python 3.8 I was wondering if you could tell how to avoid printing extra empty line when using your second option. It does do the job, but it creates extra empty lines after each row of data in the output file. I've also tried the third option, but it instead concatenates all rows into one line in the output file (headers and rows are on the one single line.

Comment: I was able to resolve the empty row issues by adding third argument to the output file 
 as such: newline=''. For python 2 instead we would need to use 'wb' as the second argument. And no third (newline='') argument is needed. Solution for python 3 is :   
  with open(''store_locations.csv') as infile, open('store_coords.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    csv.writer(outfile).writerows((row[1], row[5], row[6]) for row in csv.reader(infile))